# Parallel file writing performance on NFS under Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, nfs, amazon-efs

I have an issue regarding the performance of a EFS filesystem from Amazon, but I suspect the issue is with the Linux configuration.

My setup is a m4.large machine (2 cores, 8GB RAM) in AWS and the EFS drive is mounted as NFS4.1 mount type with standard setup.

I have a script that is creating unique small 1 kB files (see bellow). I'm running the script in parallel using GNU parallel utility that helps me run under a different number of parallel jobs.

The tests I've done shows that when I run 1 job only, the speed is 60kB/sec, 2 job in parallel, overall speed is almost 120kB/sec, but after that when run 3,4,10 jobs in parallel, the overall speed remains still around 120 kB/sec.

I've increased the default values of file-descriptors and open files to huge values but had no impact. The CPU is barely utilized and also memory is not very used. The network should be able to sustain up to 45MB/sec according to specs so I'm very far away from that limit too. Also the EFS limit of max throughput is around 105 MB/sec.

What else can I setup to allow more file to get written in parallel except increasing the number of cores on the machine? (guess file writes transforms to tcp connections for NFS mounts)

The script used:

```
#!/bin/bash
value="$(<source1k.txt)"
host="$(hostname)"
client=$1
mkdir output4/"$host"
for i in {0..5000}
do
    echo "$value" > "output4/$host/File_$(printf "%s_%03d" "$client" "$i").txt"
done
```

and it is called like bellow to run on 4 parallel jobs

```
parallel -j 4 sh writefiles.sh {} ::: 1 2 3 4
```

EDIT: I tested iozone utility using 4 kB as file size (it doesn't accept 1) and the throughput test give a result saying that Children see 240MB, while Parent see 500kB (I couldn't find what this means actually, but those 500kB are close to what I measured).

Comment: My guess is that you are doing a lot of CPU processing of scripts to write very little data (1K). Try using a real benchmark program.

Comment: The cpu is around 1% for each parallel job, according to top command.

Comment: The shell is not going to use lots of CPU time, it will use calendar time which will skew your benchmark numbers. Again I recommend using a real benchmark program.

Comment: @JohnHanley please can you recommend some benchmarking tool, I tried iozone, and I got some strange results for which I couldn't find a clear explanation (I'll add them to the question)

Answer (score 1):

After multiple tests and discussions with Amazon support, it seems my bottleneck was the fact that I was writing all files to the same folder (and probably there is a lock for naming purposes). If I changed the test to write file to different folders, the speed increased a lot.